# Converting string with `\` into json or dictionary data

Tags: python, json, postgresql

I have a csv column data as below that the TA from the previous semester said we could export and import as json.

```
"""[
    {\""type\"": \""account\"", \""data\"": {\""bid\"": 12, \""acc_num\"": 22}}, 
    {\""type\"": \""card\"", \""data\"": {\""card_num\"": 85}}
]"""
```

Unlike what he said, I couldn't import it with `json` type in Postgres. But I could import it as `character varying` or `text` type. In both cases, the data is fetched into a python string as below.

```
[
    {\type\: \account\, \data\: {\bid\: 12, \acc_num\: 22}},
    {\type\: \card\, \data\: {\card_num\: 85}}
]
```

Given its original form, what do you think is a working and efficient way to turn it into a python data or json data? I've tried

1) Converting `\` into `"` with `.replace("\\",'\"')` : it didn't work well as there are `\t` and `\b` and stuffs like that.

2) `json.loads(string)` : `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes:` error. Knew I couldn't just do it as it is not a right json form, but there I tried.

edit)
One row from the csv file

name,phone,local,domain,passwd,payments,lat,lng

```
Daivd,01095434668,tfalkc,smh.com.au,8mf3trl,"""[{\""type\"": \""account\"", \""data\"": {\""bid\"": 12, \""acc_num\"": 710831175086172}}, {\""type\"": \""card\"", \""data\"": {\""card_num\"": 8543466885434668}}, {\""type\"": \""card\"", \""data\"": {\""card_num\"": 1221510412215104}}, {\""type\"": \""card\"", \""data\"": {\""card_num\"": 4871213148712131}}]""",37.6274,126.98167
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the input? Can we have sample data from `csv`

Comment: @Vishnudev The first one is what I directly copy pasted from that specific column data (though spread it through multiple lines)

Comment: Please show one row from the csv file. BTW who has built that csv file and how?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Added one row from the CSV file. It was the TA and from what I've heard, this is a garbage data made just so we could practice...

Answer (score 4):

This is *one way* of getting a valid Python object from what you posted, but I think there are probably cleaner and probably less error-prone ways. After that, you can `json.dumps()` the result to be stored.

```
from ast import literal_eval

a = """[
    {\""type\"": \""account\"", \""data\"": {\""bid\"": 12, \""acc_num\"": 22}}, 
    {\""type\"": \""card\"", \""data\"": {\""card_num\"": 85}}
]"""

a = literal_eval(a.replace('\""', '"'))
```

Comment: Somewhat of an open challenge; I feel uneasy about this approach and feel that it can be broken with valid input text being escaped in this way, but I'm not seeing it or a better way forward. Breaking this would teach me something.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the csv via the `csv` module (or with pandas even it it is probably overkill here). Simply the field was not properly formatted and you will have to *unwrap* it with `literal_eval` but it is then a valid json string:

```
with open('file.csv') as fd:
    rd = csv.DictReader(fd)
    line = next(rd)   # only read first line here ; loop if you want to read more...
    line = ast.literal_eval(line)
    data = json.loads(line)
```

It gives as expected:

```
[{'data': {'acc_num': 710831175086172, 'bid': 12}, 'type': 'account'},
 {'data': {'card_num': 8543466885434668}, 'type': 'card'},
 {'data': {'card_num': 1221510412215104}, 'type': 'card'},
 {'data': {'card_num': 4871213148712131}, 'type': 'card'}]
```

Note: This code processes the example csv row given in an edit to the question.